# Shell script I am trying to get the product of odd numbers

Tags: shell

```
mul=1    
i=0    
while [ $i -ne 10 ]    
do    
    echo "Enter Number"   
    read num    
    if [ `expr $num % 2` -ne 0 ]     
    then    
        mul=`expr $mul*$num`     
    fi    
    i=`expr $i + 1`    
done    
echo mul of odd numbers = $mul
```

this is what i tried...its showing output as `1*3*5*7*9`

pls correct the error here

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might wish to tag this with the shell you're using: eg, bash, zsh, sh etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include in your question details of your input as well as the output. As per @JonClements' comment, add information about which shell your script is being interpreted with. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

"*" has a special meaning, hence you need to escape it and need to have a space between the two variables like:

```
mul=`expr $mul \* $num`
```

Note aside- Use of back ticks are discouraged and you may want to use something instead like:

```
mul=$(expr $mul \* $num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your don't provide some details (see my comment above) I can't guarantee this answers your question and produces the desired result. This assumes your shell is bash. Please inform me and I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Consider the changes below. The relevant part is the change from `expr ...` to `$(( ... ))`, which is bash's [built-in arithmetic expression evaluator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html).

```
#!env bash

MUL=1
I=0
while [ $I -ne 10 ]
do
    echo "Enter Number"
    read NUM
    if [[ $(($NUM % 2)) -ne 0 ]] ; then
        MUL=$(($MUL * $NUM))
    fi
    I=$(($I + 1))
done
echo MUL of odd numbers = $MUL
```

This produces the following output:

```
$ sh foo.sh
Enter Number
1
Enter Number
2
Enter Number
3
Enter Number
4
Enter Number
5
Enter Number
6
Enter Number
7
Enter Number
8
Enter Number
9
Enter Number
0
MUL of odd numbers = 945
```